# MAMP File Permissions

Tags: permissions, apache

I am using MAMP Pro 4 on Windows 10 to develop WordPress sites.

When an image is imported into the media library, the original image is placed in the uploads folder without proper permissions. WordPress generates image sizes from this image and places them all in the wp-content/uploads folder, all standard WordPress functionality. All the images are fine except the the original image. For the original image, I get the message that "You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object." I then have to go through a process to add Full permissions for the computer user for this image. This is difficult when I have many images.

I have contacted MAMP support but they are unable to help me resolve the issue.

Comment: This is a Windows-specific issue and seems to be pretty much off-topic. Sounds as if it's not a file permission but a file ownership issue. Simply google this error message and you'll find https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/you-must-have-read-permission-to-view-the/9f4fa98a-8502-48c0-bd1a-32af9a436db4 and other great resources to solve your problem.

Comment: I am also having this same issue. I noticed this happens outside of WordPress locally as well using function like this still breaks the image file permissions: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]['tmp_name'], $target_file)